# Multer Error when trying to upload image to cloudinary

Tags: node.js, express, multer, cloudinary

I'm building a crud application using mern stack which allows the user to use a form to upload images and input other pieces of data such as product name, description, quantity and price. When testing the api endpoint in postman I get this error.

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\React Applications\Nifet Health\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Multipart.<anonymous> (C:\React Applications\Nifet Health\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:107:7)
    at Multipart.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at HeaderParser.cb (C:\React Applications\Nifet Health\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:358:14)
    at HeaderParser.push (C:\React Applications\Nifet Health\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:162:20)
    at SBMH.ssCb [as _cb] (C:\React Applications\Nifet Health\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:394:37)
    at feed (C:\React Applications\Nifet Health\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:248:10)
    at SBMH.push (C:\React Applications\Nifet Health\node_modules\streamsearch\lib\sbmh.js:104:16)
    at Multipart._write (C:\React Applications\Nifet Health\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:567:19)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
```

```
/ @desc     Create product
// @route    POST /api/products
// @access   Private
const createProduct = asyncHandler(upload.single('image'), async(req, res) => {
    if(!req.body.name || !req.body.price || !req.body.quantity || !req.body.description){
        throw new Error('Please add all fields')
    }
      // Upload image to cloudinary
    const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.file.path);

    // Create new product
    const product = await Product.create({
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        quantity:  req.body.quantity,
        description: req.body.description,
        cloudinary_id: result.public_id
        
    })

    res.status(200).json(result)
})
```

multer file

```
const multer = require("multer");
const path = require("path");

// Multer config
module.exports = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({}),
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);  
    if (ext !== ".jpg" && ext !== ".jpeg" && ext !== ".png") {
      cb(new Error("File type is not supported"), false);
      return;
    }
    cb(null, true);
  },
});
```

Comment: What does your request look like?

Comment: I took a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/yJM3NfJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your request the field name for the file is missing. It *must* match the string you set in `upload.single('<fieldName>')`.

So in your postman-example set `image` as the name for your file.

It also mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage):

> It is important that you use the name field value from the form in
> your upload function. This tells multer which field on the request it
> should look for the files in. If these fields aren't the same in the
> HTML form and on your server, your upload will fail